# Make a fixed width and height html

Tags: html, css

I am new in html.

And I want to create a page which has a fixed height and width.
Also the width and height is windows width and height.

If I resize the browser ,i want the width and height not to be change, and has a scroller to see the whole page

Comment: please read and experiment about overflow: visible;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px;">
Text to try. Text to try. Text to try. Text to try. Text to try. Text to try. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the Website to fullscreen width and height you can do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body{
            width:100vw;
            height:100vh;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        h1 {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        p{
            background-color: blueviolet;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium
        recusandae dolorem incidunt perspiciatis ipsa nulla. Maxime assumenda
        mollitia, magnam obcaecati impedit iusto accusamus pariatur, natus
        exercitationem dolorum quia aperiam voluptates!
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium
        recusandae dolorem incidunt perspiciatis ipsa nulla. Maxime assumenda
        mollitia, magnam obcaecati impedit iusto accusamus pariatur, natus
        exercitationem dolorum quia aperiam voluptates!
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium
        recusandae dolorem incidunt perspiciatis ipsa nulla. Maxime assumenda
        mollitia, magnam obcaecati impedit iusto accusamus pariatur, natus
        exercitationem dolorum quia aperiam voluptates!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I recommend to set the widht to 98vw and the height to 97vh or something like that. I think this should get the result you want?

Notice: This will not work properly in a code snippet. You must have the meta-tag in the head of the actual Website.